# Why does Vectorization fail with larger numbers but Map and Apply work?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, apply

I'm trying to further understand the difference between Map, Apply, and Vectorization, and just encountered a challenge I don't understand: for small numbers, these three functions achieve the same outcome, but for large numbers Vectorization appears to fail. Here's what I mean:

```
# get a simple dataframe set up
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = range(10)
y = range(10,20)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = zip(x,y), columns = ['x','y']) 

# define a simple function to test map, apply, and vectorization with
def simple_power(num1, num2):
    return num1 ** num2

# use Map, Apply, and Vectorization to apply the function to every row in the dataframe
df['map power'] = list(map(simple_power, *(df['x'], df['y'])))
df['apply power'] = df.apply(lambda row: simple_power(row['x'], row['y']), axis=1)
df['optimize power'] = simple_power(df['x'], df['y'])
```

Everything works:

```
in: df.head()
out:    x   y   map power   apply power     vectorized power
0       0   10  0           0               0
1       1   11  1           1               1
2       2   12  4096        4096            4096
3       3   13  1594323     1594323         1594323
4       4   14  268435456   268435456       268435456
```

Here's where things get confusing: if I replace my x and y with larger ranges, map and apply still work, but vectorization fails:

```
# set up dataframe with larger numbers to multiply together
x = range(100)
y = range(100,200)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = zip(x,y), columns = ['x','y'])
```

Then if I re-run map, apply, and vectorization, I get a wonky output for vectorization:

```
in: df.head()
out:
```

[image]

Map and Apply are consistent with each other, but Vectorization gives a nonsense results.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8987 and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10964 are where your problem is foundering.

When using `**` in your function you are implicitly using numpy.power When you overflow the integer you don't see the error.

This is a known bug and should be getting fixed.